# Who is the companion Mia?

Tags: fallout-76

So I was watching a video about someone who has npc's spawn at his base and he said his companion is Mia. Around the 1:18 mark they say this.

Who is Mia? Can someone show me what she looks like?

Answer (score 7):

I wonder if they're saying their companion is M.I.A, missing in action, because they're showing an empty bedroom, indicating that they don't have a companion at the moment?